# Solidity compile Expected token Comma got 'Identifier'

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

I'm trying to compile a contract in the [solidity browser compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) and get this error:

> Expected token Comma got 'Identifier'
>               person.setRent(uint256 _rent);

What is the token Comma in this case?

My contract:

```
contract Landlord is user {
    string public landlordName;
    string public physicalAddress;
    function Landlord(
        string _name,
        string _physicalAddress){

        landlordName = _name;
        physicalAddress = _physicalAddress;
    }

    function setRent(uint256 _rent, address _tenantAddress){
        Tenant person = Tenant(_tenantAddress);
        person.setRent(uint256 _rent);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tl;dr: Get rid of the uint256.

The changes I had to make to get your code working are to:

- Define a contract `User` as your contract code refers to **user** in `contract Landlord is user`. I renamed **user** to **User** to keep with the case convention;
- Define a contract `Tenant` as your contract code refers to the statement `Tenant person = Tenant(_tenantAddress);`;
- Define a method `setRent(uint256 _rent)` in the contract `Tenant` as your contract code calls `setRent(...)` in the statement `person.setRent(uint256 _rent);`; and
- Remove the `uint256` from your call to `setRent(...)`.

Here's the code I modified to get your code to compile correctly:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract User {
}

contract Tenant {
    address tenant;
    uint256 rent;

    function Tenant(address _tenant) {
        tenant = _tenant;
    }

    function setRent(uint256 _rent) {
        rent = _rent;
    }
}

contract Landlord is User {
    string public landlordName;
    string public physicalAddress;

    function Landlord(
      string _name,
      string _physicalAddress) {
        landlordName = _name;
        physicalAddress = _physicalAddress;
    }

    function setRent(uint256 _rent, address _tenantAddress){
        Tenant person = Tenant(_tenantAddress);
        person.setRent(_rent);
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of your modified code compiling in the Solidity realtime compiler and runtime:

[image]

Comment: You  might want to put a "Tl;dr: Get rid of the uint256." at the top

Answer (score 2):

Note that a bracket is missed in  the end   `}`, please provide the whole code. note that the `setRent` has 2 parameters while you are calling it with just one parameter, you are overloading this function so you need to define it in your previous code.